# i want to call this 3d array

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

how can i this function
this is an 3D array
i want to scan from user the number of row ,colum,cell then send 3D array

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    void School (int(*ptr)[int col][int cell] );//this is a user function 

    void main (void){
    int row ;//number of row 
    int col ;//number of colum
    int cell ;//number of cell
    
    printf("Enter Number OF School Layers \n");
    scanf("%d",&row);
    printf("Enter Number OF Classes in each Layer \n");
    scanf("%d",&col);
    printf("Enter Number OF Students in each Class \n");
    scanf("%d",&cell);
    

    
    int arr [row][col][cell];
    
    

    School(arr,row,col,cell);//calling of function 

    }
    void School (int(*ptr)[int col][int cell] ){//i want what write here
    
    }
```

in this code i have problem

Comment: i want to scan from user the number of row and colum and cell then send the 3D array

Comment: What do you mean by "send 3D array"? What would be the result of that?

Comment: "i want to scan from user the number of row ,colum,cell" That part seems to be already done by your code.

Comment: This `School(arr,row,col,cell);//calling of function` does not match the prototype `void School (int(*ptr)[int col][int cell] );//this is a user function`. The attempted call gives four parameters, the prototype declares that there should only be one. Can you decisde which one you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to update the function prototype to accept dimensions before the array parameter (pointer to array actually).

```
void School (int rows, int cols, int cells, int arr[rows][cols][cells]);
```

Then invoke it as:

```
School(row, col, cell, arr);
```

The actual scanning code would be:

```
void School (int rows, int cols, int cells, int arr[rows][cols][cells]) {
for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
for (int cell = 0; cell < cells; ++cell)
   scanf("%d", &arr[row][col][cell]);
}
```

GCC has extensions that allows to declare the parameters, before passing it.

```
void School (int rows, cols, cells; int arr[rows][cols][cells], int rows, int cols, int cells);
```

This would let you call the function as:

```
School(arr, row, col, cell);
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, I am grateful to you for helping me..

Answer (score 0):

```
void School (size_t layers, size_t col, size_t cell, int (*ptr)[col][cell])
{
        
}
```